# Bad references of files in a XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, file, reference

I'm trying to copy/paste my XCode project in an other folder of my Mac but when I open it in the new folder, all the files are in red like there was not in the project.
But the files are in the good arborescence of the project.

I already try to delete them and add them but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: What does "arborescence" mean?

Comment: [Arborescence shows up on stack overflow a lot more often than you might have realized...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arborescence+)

Comment: Anyway I'm pretty sure he means the directory tree of the project.

Comment: The arborescence is all the folders and sub-folders of the project. It's the tree representation of the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only the reference now! delete those files and drag them to the project again, while doing so, please select the "copy items to destination folder" option

Comment: That's what I did. But it changes nothing. When I copy/paste the folder somewhere else, all the files are still in red...

Comment: What option I have to choose : "Create folders for any added folders" or "Create folders references for any added folders" ?

Comment: Create group for any added folders, add targets to and copy items into destinations group folder

Comment: Did you check the three boxes?

Comment: ok, avoid copy paste and drag each file from the folder to your new folder separately